# How can I change the owner for a list of schemas

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to change the owner to dbo for a list of schemas. For a single schema I can do this with:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::SchemaName TO dbo
```

E.g. I want to disown a single user from every schema. To get a list of schemas that he owns I query the database with

```
SELECT name FROM  sys.schemas WHERE principal_id = USER_ID('db_user')
```

How can I take the set of schema names I get and change the ownership of these schemas with the first query I gave you?

Comment: I think its just dynamic SQL, based on the queries you wrote. Or you are looking for more native solution?

Comment: I thought that there may be a native solution but a dynamic solution like the one from @DanGuzman is fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is with a cursor like the example below.

```
DECLARE
  @AlterAuthorizationStatement nvarchar(MAX)
, @SchemaName sysname;
DECLARE SchemaList CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT name
    FROM  sys.schemas
    WHERE principal_id = USER_ID('db_user');
OPEN SchemaList;
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM SchemaList INTO @SchemaName;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;
    SET @AlterAuthorizationStatement =
        N'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::' + @SchemaName + N' TO dbo;';
    RAISERROR ('Executing %s', 0, 0, @AlterAuthorizationStatement) WITH NOWAIT;
    EXEC sp_executesql @AlterAuthorizationStatement;
END;
CLOSE SchemaList;
DEALLOCATE SchemaList;
GO
```